# Spring Refresh Application Context Data - PostConstruct

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Below is my project structure.

SpringWebProject-A --> Services-A ---> **CommonServices** 
SpringWebProject-B --> Services-B ---> **CommonServices**

I have one service inside **CommonServices** project which is annotated with **@javax.annotation.PostConstruct** annotation.

Now when if there is some updation in data from SpringWebProject-A I need to update the map returned by the service annotated with PostConstruct service and this service is also used by SpringWebProject-B.

Now when I update data and call a service with PostConstruct annotation from SpringWebProject-A it updates the data but the updated data is not available to 
SpringWebProject-B.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not at all clear, what your exact problem is. Can you please provide the relevant source code?